# open file, save duplicate with different name

Tags: c++, file-io

Hello c++ newbie over here !!!

I am working on a very simple program, that opens files saved into a vector, reverses the content text for each files, and saves the new file.
I am using code blocks

### example:

- open "test.txt"
- reverse lines
- creates "m_test.txt"
- delete "test.txt"
- do the same to other files in the vector.

I get an error in : 
`outFile.open( foundFiles[i].insert(3,"m_"),  fstream::in);`

" no matching function for call to 'std::basic_fstream::open(std::basic_string&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'| "

### here is the code so far:

```
 string reverseLine(string message);

 string reverseLine(string message)
 {
    string reversed;
    int i = message.length()  -1;
    while (i>=0)
        {
        reversed = reversed + message[i];
        i = i -1;
        }
    return reversed;
 }


 void filesToModify();

 void filesToModify() // put files into vector
 {

 fstream filesInVector;  // files open from the vector
 string  openFLine;      // lines read from the files read from the vector

 fstream outFile;        //files saved after reversing the files

 vector <string> foundFiles;   //vector holding all the files to be reversed


 foundFiles.push_back("e:/file_1.txt");
 foundFiles.push_back("e:/file_2.txt");
 foundFiles.push_back("e:/file_3.txt");

 for (int i=0; i<foundFiles.size(); i++) // read the files inside the vector
        {
            filesInVector.open(foundFiles[i],  fstream::in);

            while (!filesInVector.eof())
            {
            getline(filesInVector,openFLine);
            outFile<<reverseLine(openFLine);
            outFile.open( foundFiles[i].insert(3,"m_"),  fstream::in); // add "m_" to the created file
            foundFiles[i].close();    // close the  file

            std::remove(foundFiles[i]); // remove the original file
           }
        }

  int main()
 {

 filesToModify();

 }
```

Comment: For older standards use `std::string::c_str()` to pass as argument for `std::ofstream:open()`.

Comment: please explain sir, I am not comfortable with pointers yet :)

Comment: Having a read at the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) should help. No furrther explabnation needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
outFile.open( foundFiles[i].insert(3,"m_").c_str (),  fstream::in);
```

C++ used to have no string datatype. It was added later in the STL (standard template library. These early C++ versions used a char* (pointer to character). A string was simply represented by a character array, terminated by a 0 char (char with code 0). The pointer held the address of the first char of this array.

Some functions still expect a char* instead of a string.
Method c_str () of STL class string converts an STL string to a char*.